# macos unable to connect to L2TP server

Tags: macos-mojave

I'm trying to connect my macOS (10.14.4) to L2TP server, but my Mac just pop up a window:

VPN Connection
Your connection failed because of an incorrect PPP setting. Verify your settings and try reconnecting.
[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWzxO.png)

I have tried using my iphone to connect L2TP server and it worked perfectly (in the same local network).

Did anyone get the same issue before?

Answer (score 0):

Delete your /etc/ppp/options and try to run this command.

sudo bash -c 'echo "plugin L2TP.ppp">>/etc/ppp/options'